# UIImageView.image = mImage leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uikit, uiimageview

I have thread2 loop where i do assembly (create from raw bytes data) some UIImage
in every iteration of this loop

```
thread2loop()
{
  //make UIIamge here

  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setUiImage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];     
}
```

there and then i call setUIImage method on the main thread

```
- (void) setUiImage
{
    self.imageView.image = nil;     
    self.imageView.image = mImage;  
    [mImage release];    
}
```

it is working but the Instruments , leaks application shows to me that there are
UIImage leaks here and i do not know how to @#$! get rid of it! (im sad and little tired 
and bored), help, what to do, tnx

Comment: Please show the code to make UIImage. And also have you created the autorelease pool for the thread?

Comment: mImage looks like being a property, pleas show us how this is declared and how you set it.

Comment: this code is `mImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];` no autorelease involved as far as i know

Comment: no property is defined, there is only the `UIImage * mImage;` field in my containing class

Answer (score 0):

Surround your threaded code with...

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

//threaded code....

[pool release];
```

Comment: why?    i create image once then i release it once, dont understand such leak and im angry because of hunting it for 3hours

Answer (score 0):

Classic producer/consumer problem. Your producer thread is probably outrunning the main thread (the consumer). I'd recommend keeping a queue of images (instead of the single mImage), guarded by a lock which you enqueue images onto (from your background queue), and dequeue images from your main queue. Or you could use GCD, which makes this even easier. Instead of using mImage to hold onto the created image, you could just use a block which would retain the image and then set it on your image view in the main queue. Something like:

```
thread2loop() {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    while (...) {
        __block id self_block = self; // (don't want to retain self in the block)
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            block_self.imageView.image = img;  
            [img release];
        }); 
    }
    [pool drain]; // release is outdated for autorelease pools
}
```

Warning: Doing this too much will quickly run the device out of memory and cause your app to be killed. You probably want to make sure that your use of this technique is limited to creating a small number of images.

Comment: what do you mean 'outrunning'? you mean that my producer thread is producing more images than consummer thread can set to display?? it is not such case - the two are synchronized by `performSelectorOnMainThread: waitUntilDone: YES`- it is called like normal synchronous function calls - the problem i think is in releasing image in uiImageView, nilling it seem to not give a result in releasing it

Comment: Correct you are, it should be synchronized in that instance. Wild guess, have you looked to make sure that your imageView is being released properly? It would be helpful if you posted more code.

Comment: imageView will be released at the end of the app; i think i need to release imegeView's .image and dont know how to do it - as far as i know setting new image to .image rekeases previous image setted but i had leaks (raported in Instruments) still